# Can a mac do a bitwise copy of a USB disk with proprietary disk format?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, copy-paste

I have a USB disk with a propietary format that I want to bitwise clone to a new identical drive.

I have CCC but the disk doesn't show up in Finder.  It does appear in Disk Utility.

I tried Terminal command of "mount" and do not see a device that might be it, so the dd command probably isn't an option.

Any ideas?

Can it be done on a Windows or Linux machine?

Thanks for any help,
-deac  :-)

Comment: `dd` seems like the way to go, here. Try to run  `df` before and after plugging you USB drive. Is there a new line that appears?

Comment: Since it shows in Disk Utility, check if it is Hidden drive.

Comment: As it shows up in Disk Utility, you should be able to find it using `diskutil list` in the Terminal. That should provide you with a name to use for `dd`.